# Sampling from a secondary datatable to the main datatable based on a condition

Tags: r, datatable, sample

I have two datatables `dt_main` and `dt_unit`.

```
set.seed(1)
dt_main<-data.table(ID=sample(1:20,size=10),Group=sample(1:3,size=10,replace=TRUE),Unit=0)
dt_unit<-data.table(Group=sample(1:3,size=10,replace=TRUE),Unit_id=sample(1000:3000,size=10,replace=TRUE))
```

`dt_main` look like this:

```
> dt_main
    ID Group Unit
 1:  4     1    0
 2:  7     1    0
 3:  1     1    0
 4:  2     2    0
 5: 13     2    0
 6: 19     2    0
 7: 11     2    0
 8: 17     3    0
 9: 14     1    0
10:  3     3    0
```

`dt_unit` look like this:

```
> dt_unit
    Group Unit_id
 1:     1    2624
 2:     1    2963
 3:     1    1974
 4:     1    1800
 5:     2    1851
 6:     1    1930
 7:     1    1325
 8:     2    1329
 9:     2    1553
10:     2    2445
```

I would like to fill in the `Unit` column in `dt_main` by sampling one `Unit_id` from `dt_unit` to `dt_main` with the same `Group`.

For example for the first row in `dt_main` (so `Group`=1), the code should lookup at `dt_unit` and find the rows where `Group` is 1 (see below), and select a `Unit_id` and insert it in the `Unit`.

```
> dt_unit[Group==1]
   Group Unit_id
1:     1    2624
2:     1    2963
3:     1    1974
4:     1    1800
5:     1    1930
6:     1    1325
```

I tried something like this which assigned the same number to each row:

```
dt_main[,Unit:=sample(dt_unit[Group==Group]$Unit_id,size=1)]
```

I also attempted `sapply` but no good.

Comment: Do you want same `Unit_id` for all the values of `Group`? So `Group = 1` would have the same value from `dt_unit` ?

Comment: No, i want random values each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution where we match the Groups and sample 1 value every time,

```
dt_main$Unit <- sapply(dt_main$Group, function(i) {
                                  v1 <- dt_unit$Unit_id[dt_unit$Group %in% i]; 
                                  if (length(v1) > 0) {sample(v1, 1) } else {NA}
                                  })


#    ID Group Unit
# 1:  4     1 1930
# 2:  7     1 1325
# 3:  1     1 1325
# 4:  2     2 1329
# 5: 13     2 2445
# 6: 19     2 2445
# 7: 11     2 1851
# 8: 17     3   NA
# 9: 14     1 1930
#10:  3     3   NA
```

Comment: I know this changes the question but is there an easy fix for the following: I want to add a second condition while looking up the value. For example, assume there is also a `Size` column in each table and when looking up at the second datatable, i want to sample from the rows of which: `Group` column matches and `dt_main$Size>dt_unit$Size`.

Comment: Should be an easy fix. One way come to mind you can add a `v2` under `v1` in `sapply()` function which will only get  the unit_ids of the ones that satisfy your condition. Then `intersect` v1 and v2 and sample as per usual

Answer (score 1):

You can join `dt_main` and `dt_unit` by `Group` and select a random row for each `ID`.

Using `dplyr`, you can do this by :

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(dt_main, dt_unit, by = 'Group') %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(1)


#     ID Group Unit_id
#   <int> <int>   <int>
# 1     1     1    1800
# 2     2     2    2445
# 3     3     3      NA
# 4     4     1    2963
# 5     7     1    1800
# 6    11     2    1851
# 7    13     2    1553
# 8    14     1    1325
# 9    17     3      NA
#10    19     2    2445
```

I removed `Unit` column from `data.table` creation.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer with `mapply`, which I used for the case with multiple conditions. In this case, while looking up I check if `Group` columns match AND a new column (`Size`) in dt_main is larger than that of `dt_unit`. As the OP I had to add another condition to the original post and therefore adding this solution to help future users.

```
my_fun<-function(var1,var2)
{
  d<-dt_unit[(Group%in%var1)&(Size>=var2)]
  if(nrow(d)>=2){
  sample(x=d$Unit_id,size=1,replace=T)
  }else
  {d$Unit_id}
}
vars1<-dt_main$Group
vars2<-dt_main$Size
dt_main$Unit<-mapply(my_fun,vars1,vars2)
```